# Displaying LiveData from Room in Activity (Android Studio kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

Im trying to display the LiveData (all Devices) in a LazyColumn item list in my Activity. However I dont get the Data from my Room DB in my Acitvity.

DeviceDao: 
Here I make the query to get all Devices from my Room DB

```js
@Query("SELECT * FROM DeviceData ORDER BY id ASC")
fun getAllDevices(): LiveData<List<DeviceEntity>>
```

DeviceRepository:

```js
val readAllData: LiveData<List<DeviceEntity>> = deviceDao.getAllDevices()
```

DeviceViewModel:

```js
private val repository: DeviceRepository
private val readAllData: LiveData<List<DeviceEntity>>

init {
    val deviceDao = DeviceDatabase.getDatabase(application).deviceDao()
    repository = DeviceRepository(deviceDao)
    readAllData = repository.readAllData
}
```

MenuActivity: 
In my MenuActivity I want to display all the Devices from my Room DB in the LazyColumn item list but sadly I get no devices. There also isnt any error that I could google.

I would love if someone could help me figure out my mistake.

```js
private lateinit var deviceViewModel: DeviceViewModel
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    //DB
    deviceViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[DeviceViewModel::class.java]
    //DB END
    setContent {
        MyCatBellTheme {
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                MenuScreenUI(deviceViewModel.devices)
            }
        }
    }
}
...


@Composable
fun LiveDataComponent(deviceListLiveData: LiveData<List<DeviceEntity>>) {
    val deviceList by deviceListLiveData.observeAsState(initial = emptyList())

    if(deviceList.isEmpty()) {
        LiveDataLoadingComponent()
    } else {
        ScrollUI(deviceList)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScrollUI(deviceList: List<DeviceEntity>) {
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.9f)
    ) {
        //adds an item to the list for every raspberry pi that was added
        items(
            items = deviceList, itemContent = { person ->
                CardItem(
                    deviceTitle = person.deviceName,
                    deviceUUID = person.deviceUUID,
                    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                    imagePainter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_iconv7)
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Room DB:

There are already Devices stored in my Room DB so there is data. It just doesnt show in my LazyColumn list.

[Here is an image of my Room DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qIiN.png)

Comment: Try to pass state to LiveDataComponent instead of LiveData.

Comment: Im kind of new to android programming, what do you mean by "pass state" to the LiveDataComponent. Could you maybe explain that? Thank you! :)

Comment: Just to be sure: did you set your LiveDataComponent as content in onCreate()? Can you add the setContent{} call to the code in your question?

Comment: @MarioHuizinga I added the setContent call which calls the MenuScreenUI. That does some UI stuff and calls the LiveDataComponent() method which gets the devices passed again. If you stell need some details I can add more code. I thought it would maybe lead to more confusion if I add more. :)

Comment: I don't see any obvious error yet. After `val deviceList by` you can add a Log statement with `deviceList.size` to see if it gets executed: should be first size 0 and later size > 0. Like this you can find out if the error is before or after this point. Also you can observe the liveData from your onCreate() and Log if it is working at all.

Comment: I tried to debug my Activity after the initialization of the ViewModel. After the initialization I tried to evaluate the statement "deviceViewModel.devices", which does not give me any devices I think. At least I cant really see where they should be.

Comment: @MarioHuizinga now I logged the deviceListLiveData.value?.size which is null and the deviceList size which is 0. I dont think my Activity gets any data.

Comment: Create a getAllDevices() query without LiveData and log the contents from your repository. And so on, step by step find out what is working and what not.

Comment: @MarioHuizinga thats a good idea! I will do that thank you :)